# Is every smooth and monotonic function the solution of a smooth first order autonomous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, monotone-functions

By definition the solution $x: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $t \mapsto x(t)$ of a first order autonomous differential equation

$$\dot{x} := \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)$$

for some arbitrary function $f(x)$ must obey

$$x(t) = x(t') \rightarrow \dot{x}(t) = \dot{x}(t')$$

Looking at a graph like this

[image]

one sees that $x(t)$ must be monotone to be the solution of a first order autonomous differential equation, i.e. there must be no two $t, t'$, $t < t'$ with $x(t) = x(t')$, because there would have to be a third $t''$ between $t$ and $t'$ with $x(t'') = x(t) = x(t')$ but $\dot{x}(t'') \neq \dot{x}(t) = \dot{x}(t')$.

My question is:

> Let  $x(t)$ be an arbitrary smooth and monotone function and
>   $\dot{x}(t)$ its (smooth) derivative. Consider the set $f$ of ordered
>   pairs
>
> $$f = \{\langle x(t),\dot{x}(t)\rangle\ |\ t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> which by definition is a function $f: \text{range}(x) \rightarrow
>  \text{range}(\dot{x})$. Can it be shown that $f$ must be smooth?

(Maybe this is a standard exercise?) If not so: What are specific counter-examples?

The other way around: Since $x(t)$ must be monotone, $\dot{x}(t)$ has to be positive or negative (for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$).

> Can it be shown that for each smooth positive or negative function
>   $f(x)$ there is a smooth monotone function $x(t)$ that is the
>   solution of $\dot{x} = f(x)$?

If not so: What are specific counter-examples?

Comment: Surely, $f$ is a mapping between the *ranges* of $x$ and $\dot x$, not between their *domains*? In any case, consider the example $x(t)=t^3$, which gives $f(x)=3x^{2/3}$ – if I have understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard counter-example for a smooth inverse for a monotone function is $x(t)=t^3$ at $t=0$. As an autonomous ODE this gives
$$
\dot x(t)=3t^2=3x(t)^{2/3}
$$
which is not smooth at $x=0$.

If you can exclude that using generic terms you should be fine.

---

For the second question, consider the standard example $f(x)=x^2$. It does not have solutions over the entirety of $\Bbb R$. On the other hand, a standard exercise is to show that for linearly bounded $f$ you get global solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Is "excluding that using generic terms" straightforward, in your opinion? Maybe like this: "smooth almost everywhere" or "smooth except for at most finitely many arguments" or possibly "smooth except for at most one argument"?

Comment: No, you only need to ensure the conditions of the inverse function theorem in every relevant point. Which means that you need to exclude points of zero derivative.